# how to use cakePHP addUnauthenticatedActions() with tokens in the URL

Tags: authentication, token, cakephp-4.x

I am working in Cake 4 and have successfully included the authentication plugin that replaces the deprecated Auth(). To avoid an infinite redirect loop I have added the actions I want excluded from authentication similar to that shown in the Cake CMS tutorial.

UsersController:

$this->Authentication->addUnauthenticatedActions(['login', 'forgotpassword', 'resetpassword']);

I intend to use tokens for the resetpassword action and a reset link sent to a user will look something like this.

http://localhost/axletrace/users/resetpassword7724d1bbd400e0bd624411549a2dd64c6b73481e

Because the action requested now looks like 'resetpassword7724d1bbd400e0bd624411549a2dd64c6b73481e', it is not a match to the exclusions listed above and it redirects to the login page.

I have tried using a wildcard as shown below but it makes no difference.
$this->Authentication->addUnauthenticatedActions(['login', 'forgotpassword', 'resetpassword*']);

Given that the token is not a static value what is the way to handle this situation. I am trying to use the token as an authentication token only. I would prefer not to use JWT Authentication and I am not worrying about session tokens for the time being.

Any help would be apprecated, thanks.

Comment: Are you using `http://localhost/axletrace/users/resetpassword7724d1bbd400e0bd624411549a2dd64c6b73481e` instead of `http://localhost/axletrace/users/resetpassword/7724d1bbd400e0bd624411549a2dd64c6b73481e` on purpose? Why? The latter would make all of this easy.

Comment: Thanks Greg. The first version of the URL is correct. No '/' after 'resetpassword'. The hash at the end is not part of the URL. It is meant to act as an authentication token. Similar to what Stack Overflow do with their reset password links. Eg.
https://stackoverflow.com/account/recover?recoveryToken=63%3a3%3a913%2c16%3a02bc7c7babd91625%2c

Comment: But *why*? The SO example you give very clearly has a delineation between the "action" (`recover`) and the parameter. That's pretty standard for URLs that I see everywhere. There's always a `/` or a `?` that makes it easy for the application to know where the "route" part ends and where the parameter part starts.